# Who can help me . I am interested to be a reviwer

Tags: peer-review

Shall anybody recommend me a journal -in the field of analytical chemistry- that can easily offer me to be a reviewer in it . I am very interested to do so although it will be the first!. I am a master student . I have one paper not published yet but has big chance .

Comment: Given the premises, you haven't yet enough experience to become a reviewer, a role which requires expertise in the field.

Comment: The English may need some polishing...

Answer (score 2):

Talk to your supervisor. If she feels you're capable of reviewing articles, she can direct one of the reviewer invitations she receives to you. If not, then she should be able to tell you what you need to do before you can be a peer reviewer.